# ASP MVC 4 client side character max validation not showing message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have a character limit I'm trying to place on a specific field using ASP MVC 4 client side validation. Unfortunately this field can be auto-populated by a drop down list and, since the values are maintained by our staff, occasionally a value is entered larger than 12 characters or with too much whitespace.

The client side validation seems to catch the field just fine (highlights it in red and will not allow the form to post), but I will not display the message. We have other fields in the same form that do so, so I'm not sure what is going on. Obviously our jQuery scripts and `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` command are set properly

**Model**

```
    [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 12 characters")]
    public string DRMCompanyId { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="M-editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DRMCompanyId, new {@class="required"})
</div>
<div class="M-editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DRMCompanyId, new { maxLength = 10 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DRMCompanyId)
</div>
```

For reference the below validation works. This field is in the same form:

**Model**

```
    [DisplayName("Effective Date")]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="M-editor-field">          
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, new { maxlength = 10 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
</div>
```

Comment: `MaxLength` and `MinLength` unobtrusive validation are only supported since MVC 5.1 [What's New in ASP.NET MVC 5.1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Unobtrusive).

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following Attribute instead of yours:

`[StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 12 characters")]`

This is the right DataAnnotation for your purposes.

[More info about this attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`[StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 12 characters")]`

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ketjUe)